# Noob user, run into an error on prototyping attempt

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

I'm making my first attempt at creating a Service and API prototype. I've been following this guide https://medium.com/madhash/prototype-your-app-with-firebase-api-7a51325de6f2

I've reached the step of "Run > Run Function > Initialize" but i'm getting an error relating to the code.gs I've pasted in from https://gist.github.com/dottedsquirrel/b248e5098fe2a9c860ed60f7db7c7e1d

The error i'm getting is "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 49, file "Code")"
When I look at the line of code it states:  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID);

Can anyone provide me some pointers as to how to resolve this error? Could there be a problem with the data set I created? The data sheet i'm pointing looks like this:

| ID | ItemFunctionalID | ItemFunctionalID | Type | CustodianGroupID | ProcessScopeID | CountryID | StartDt | EndDt | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 28948190843 | Release | 100199 | 200002 | 01/01/2021 | Active |  |  |  |
| 2 | 28948190843 | Release | 100011 |  | 01/01/2021 | Active |  |  |  |
| 3 | 28948191024 | Release | 100199 | 200002 | 01/01/2021 | Active |  |  |  |
| 4 | 28948191024 | Release | 100011 |  | 01/01/2021 | Active |  |  |  |
| 5 | 28948191031 | Release | 100199 | 200002 | 01/01/2021 | Active |  |  |  |

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run the code by:

> Run> Run Function > Initialize

And it didn't work, instead try to go to select function, select initialize and then press the triangle on the left to run the script.

[image]